# how to call class function in static object?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is the example:

```
export class cls1{
  str1:string;

  constructor(s:string){
    this.str1 = s;
  }

  func1(){
    return "hello " + this.str1;
  }
}

export class AppComponent  {

static obj2:cls1= JSON.parse(`{"str1":"efgh"}`);

AppComponent.obj2.func1(); //  func1 is not a function
}
```

The problem is the function member is not familiar in the static object.
I get error: func1 is not a function

Comment: I am not an angular expert, but obj2 seems to be an instance here so you cant call the method. try cls1.func1()

Comment: Thanks, but cls1 is not static so that every time there is an instance it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do here? This does not look like any use-case I could think of. Or are you just messing around, trying stuff with typescript? How would a function magically appear from a `JSON.parse` call which just contains an object :)?

Anyways, the closest I could come up with to get that function working is by changing your code to this:

```
class cls1{
  str1:string;

  constructor(s:string){
    this.str1 = s;
  }

  func1(){
    alert(this.str1);
  }
}

class AppComponent  {

   static obj2:cls1= new cls1(JSON.parse('{"str1":"efgh"}').str1);
}

AppComponent.obj2.func1(); // alert: 'efgh'
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v823ra83/)

Let's ignore the coding style errors for now, and be on your way :)

Comment: Thanks, the JSON.parse is jast for example.
I have a really large static object has a lot of members and functions and I would like to turn the function on the values of existing members

Comment: And, Your's code accepted error: (SystemJS) cls1 is not a constructor.

Comment: Ok, in typescript it's work, but I work in angular2 - typescript, and it's accepted error: "(SystemJS) cls1 is not a constructor" :-(

Comment: That's because you are probably missing an import somewhere. Are you using an IDE?

Comment: Yes, i'm using WebStorm.

Comment: Are you importing the `cls1` class inside your appcomponent file?